# In Angularjs, is it possible to load multiple directives parallely?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angularjs-directive, parallel-processing

I have a table on UI with 5 columns. These columns contain different charts which are rendered using different directives i.e. custom progress bar, chart for margin, chart for target achieved, etc.
It is working fine currently.

Problem :- While loading the page, page takes around 10s to render. (data from backend takes 800-900ms to return data). When I reduce the number of chart columns from 5 to 1, time taken to render page has been drastically reduced to 2.5s. Time take in rendering page keeps on increasing by 1-2 seconds as I add columns one by one.

I am looking if there is a way I can call 5 directives in parallel at a time so that time taken to render page becomes somewhere around 3-4 seconds.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: data for 5 column coming in a single call from server or you have column specific calls ? and how many rows it has?

Comment: Data for all 5 column is coming in sigle call from server. Data returned has contails list of object where each object has 36 properties. At a time I received max 25 objects.
1 json - 25 object where each object contains 36 properties/fields.

Total time taken for this is 800/900 ms

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your problem I have below finding to share.

1. Directive always runs in parallel except they are not nested to each other. Assuming in your scenario they are in ng-repeat loop so they will run parallel.
2. Avoid calling all 25 objects in one go (have pagination kind of use case) this will save server level time.
3. Avoid rendering all the chart on DOM at the same time. DOM rendering is the most expensive process in load cycle. Try rendering 5 but display one with display block and rest with display none then show them one by one. this will avoid DOM freezing. try limit option in ng-repeat.

It would be great if you can share DOM code and JS code.